# Is it ok to put the adverb at the end of the sentence right after the second verb?

Tags: word-order

I have this sentence where the adverb is at the end of the sentence despite there is the second verb, which should always come at the end.

> Ich habe sehr viel gesehen heute.

Is this correct?

Comment: Similar question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55787/verb-position-with-modal-verbs/55805?r=SearchResults&s=1|11.4210#55805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find these kind of sentences in a colloquial style conversation. The "heute" is like afterthought, added to the sentence that you already said (Ich habe sehr viel gesehen), so can no longer take it back to make the grammar correct, which would of course be: Ich habe heute sehr viel gesehen.

So, don't use it in a test or such ;-)

Comment: *Afterthought* is the key point here - whenever you can rearrange the words, put the "heute" to its correct position.