# Warum ist das zweite Verb nicht am Ende?

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich habe in einem Buch den folgenden Satz gesehen:

> Ich habe reserviert auf den Namen Müller.

Meine Frage ist: Warum ist das Wort *reserviert* hier nicht am Ende des Satzes?

Comment: Aufgrund welcher Regel glaubst Du denn, dass es am Ende stehen müsste?

Comment: Ähnliche Frage, allerdings auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55787/verb-position-with-modal-verbs/55805#55805

Comment: Die Satzstellung ist im Deutschen ziemlich variabel. Man erreicht durch solche Vertauschungen auch gern Betonungen. In deinem Satz sollte wahrscheinlich "Müller" am Ende des Satzes stehen, um darauf die Betonung zu legen.

Comment: @TorstenLink Aufgrund der Regel für Perfektbildung: "Ich habe einen Tisch reserviert", "Ich habe einen Tisch auf den Namen Müller reserviert", "Ich habe auf den Namen Müller reserviert".

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/q/60589/35111

Answer (score 5):

Es ist umgangssprachlich.

> Ich habe auf den Namen Mueller reserviert.

ist die formal korrektere Formulierung.

Man kann es sich als zwei durch eine kleine Pause getrennte Aeusserungen vorstellen (als haette man vergessen, den Namen einzufuegen).

> Ich habe reserveriert ... auf den Namen Mueller.

Ich denke, dass es eine verbreitete Formulierung ist. Vielleicht ist der Ursprung, dass man z.B. in einem Restaurant das Personal erst darauf hinweist, dass man reserviert hat und dann, wenn sie in ihre Unterlagen sehen, den Namen hinzufuegt, aber das ist nur meine Spekulation.

Comment: Hier darf (und soll) man gerne begründen und belegen, soll aber nicht behaupten. Wie kommst du darauf, daß diese Satzstellung umgangssprachlich sein soll?

Comment: Es könnte auch als Ellipse gesehen werden: "Ich habe reserviert [und zwar] auf den Namen Müller."

Comment: @ tofro "...avoid making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or **personal experience**". In diesem Sinne: Ich habe diese Formulierung schon haeufiger verwendet, und als jemand, der laengere Zeit als Kellner gearbeitet hat, habe ich sie auch von vielen anderen gehoert. 2.) Waehrend ich es nicht mit Daten belegen kann, wage ich zu vermuten, dass diese Satzstellung in geschriebener und formeller gesprochener Sprache recht selten ist (offensichtlich ausser dort, wo Umgangssprache wiedergegeben wird.) @ infinitezero Ja, klingt aber ein bisschen wie Loriot.

Answer (score 4):

> Ich habe reserviert **,** **auf den Namen Müller.**

Alle Teile des Prädikats stehen im Deutschen am Ende des Hauptfelds eines Satzes, mit Ausnahme des V2-Verbs. Meistens ist das Ende des Hauptfelds auch das Ende des Haupt- oder Nebensatzes, aber eben nicht immer. Es kann im **Nachfeld** noch ein Vergleich folgen, oder eine mit Komma abgetrennte Ergänzung. So wie in deinem Beispiel, oder wie in allen Sätzen in diesem Absatz.

(Man beachte die Ausnahme, dass die nicht-V2-Teile des Prädikats als ganzes auch im Vorfeld stehen können.)

Answer (score 2):

Der Sprecher stellt den Satz etwas um, um die beiden wichtigen Informationen, die er enthält, besser zu trennen. Über den Grund kann man spekulieren: vielleicht deshalb, weil sie ihm erst in dieser Reihenfolge in den Kopf kommen. Vielleicht auch aus Rücksicht auf den Zuhörer, um ihm die beiden Informationen in der Reihenfolge zu geben, in der dieser sie braucht und gut aufnehmen kann.

> Ich habe reserviert 
> auf den Namen Müller.

Die Standard-Reihenfolge wäre:

> Ich habe auf den Namen Mueller reserviert.

Es ist aber im Deutschen natürlich erlaubt und sehr üblich, eine adverbiale Bestimmung erst am Ende des Satzes hinzuzufügen.

> Es hat noch nie einen guten Herrenausstatter gegeben in diesem Kaff.
>
> Über so etwas regt sich niemand mehr auf im 21. Jahrhundert.
>
> Es hatte selten zuvor ein so opulentes Abendessen gegeben auf der Titanic.
>
> Kannst du die Säge bitte wieder in den Keller runterbringen in die Kiste unter der Werkbank im Hobbyraum die Treppe runter links?